# Last modified date of local file. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, last-modified

In javaScript, currently reading xml files stored in `%appdata%` using jQuerys `$.ajax` function. As the file is in `%appdata%` my javaScript has access to read and write the file.

Example:

```
/**
* Read a foo.
*/
function readFoo() {
    var xmlFile = "../foo/bar.xml";

        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            url : xmlFile,
            dataType : "xml",
            success: parseFoo,
            error: reportFooFail
        });
}
```

Is it possible using jQuery or plain javaScript to get the files 'last modified' date?

Comment: No, you need a server-side script which retrieves the value for you.

Comment: Depending on the server, there are chances that you are already getting it in a response header called `Date` or something related. Check all the response headers in browser's developer tools.

Comment: @hjpotter92 If you read the question I asked, my javaScript does not deal with any 'servers'. I am reading local files (For local people!)... from my %appdata% folder (Windows box).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`request.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");` will return you the last-modified date

Use it in the success callback:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, request){
    var lastModified = request.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
 }
```

Comment: To be honest, It didn't. I'm starting to think its not possible. (If so; This is closest, will accept). All I get is null when I use this on files in my %appdata%.... Plus it's always nice to wait 24 hours before accepting an anwser.

Answer (score 0):

This works nice for me:

```
<div id="lastdatemod"></div>
...
function checkFile() {
var x = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("lastdatemod").innerHTML = x;
}
```